Golang HTMX and Templ Events and Updating
I'm well-versed in Golang, but not much in HTML / Web Development. I am trying to achieve the following using HTMX and Templ

WebServer listens for events from a stream
Those events will update an internal DB (mem storage on the server)
When an update happens, I need for the contents of the webpage(s) to be updated and refreshed from the newly updated data of the DB

I've been hitting walls with sse-events and hx-triggers as they seem to require being generated from the HTML itself to get a response to reload / update the contents on the client. Any help is greatly appreciated!

you are describing an entire chain of actions  ... as always break into baby steps and master each in turn  ...  https://v2-0v2-0.htmx.org/extensions/server-sent-events/
